# Replace commas followed by spaces with commas

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

How can I replace all commas followed by spaces (`", "`) with just commas (`","`)?

I don't want to replace spaces when they don't have a comma in front of them (`" "`).

Comment: please give example of your code

Comment: 8 year later? Seriously?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All the str_replace solutions will work.  If you want to replace all whitespaces before and after the commas

```
$str = 'cat,  dog , cow,       horse   ,mouse,moose';

$pattern = '/\s*,\s*/';
$replace = ',';
$str = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);
```

Comment: This is the REAL answer!

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick:

```
$str = "some, comma, seperated, words";
$str = str_replace(", ", ",", $str);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick?

```
$sString = str_replace(", ", ",", $sString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$str = str_replace(', ',',',$str);
```