# remove spaces before or after comma in php

Tags: php, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace comma + space with “,” but not spaces without commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290249/replace-comma-space-with-but-not-spaces-without-commas)

Here's my text

```
$x = 'first name, middle name, last name';
```

Expected Output

```
first name,middle name,last name
```

tried this

```
$x = str_replace(array(', ', ' ,', ' , '), array(',', ',', ','), $x);
```

i'm not sure this the way

Comment: Expected Behavior : Tell us what you have tried. Even it's unexpected, what result are you getting?

Comment: *i'm not sure this the way*: Does it work for you?

Answer (score 17):

```
$x = preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', ',', $x);
```

Comment: how would the expression be in java

Comment: how would it look if i want to remove spaces only before comma?