# Remove spaces before non-word character with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following C# code:

```
var sentence = "As a result , he failed the test   .";
var pattern = new Regex();
var outcome = pattern.Replace(sentence, String.Empty);
```

What should I do to the RegEx to obtain the following output:

> As a result, he failed the test.

Comment: Your pattern needs a pattern in it, what have you tried?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290249/replace-comma-space-with-but-not-spaces-without-commas

Comment: You can use `\s+\B` - but what about parentheses (like this), or dashes - like this one, or "quotes"? Not to mention, many .txt files have meaningful spaces before "non-word characters" :-|

Comment: What doesn't work? Show what you have tried.

Comment: @stribizhev - why did you add `new Regex(@" ");`? It wasn't in the OP's code...

Comment: @Kobi: I am more than sure it is a typo, because without that the code does not compile. That is why I put it there.

Comment: @stribizhev - Whether or not is a typo is not for your or I to say (even though its pretty hard to do a 4 letter typo).

Comment: @Kobi : It is just for the punctuation mark. Sorry for the ambiguity in the question.

Comment: @RaymondWong - `-`, `{`, and `"` are all punctuation marks (and there are many more) - https://regex101.com/r/cG1lA8/1

Comment: Yes. White-list approach would be the best solution to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to white-list punctuation marks that generally don't appear in English after spaces, you can use:

```
\s+(?=[.,?!])
```

- `\s+` - all white space characters. You may want `[ ]+` instead.
- `(?=[.,?!])` - lookahead. The next character should be `.`, `,`, `?`, or `!` .

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/iJ5vM8/1

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a pattern to your code that will match spaces before punctuation:

```
var sentence = "As a result , he failed the test   .";
var pattern = new Regex(@"\s+(\p{P})");
var outcome = pattern.Replace(sentence, "$1");
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: To match symbols, too, use `@"\s+([\p{S}\p{P}])"`